# Better way for using builder pattern with optional values?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

We are using the builder pattern to create some input for service, and it looks like something like this (simplified):

```
final SomeInput input = SomeInput.builder()
    .withSomeId(....) 
    .withSomeState(....)
    ...
    .build();
```

There's some attribute that we want to set in SomeInput, but only if it is present. So after creating the object, I do something like this:

```
Optional<String> secondaryId = infoProvider.getSecondaryId();
if (secondaryId.isPresent()) {
   input.setSecondaryId(secondaryId.get());
}
```

I was wondering:

a) Is there a better/cleaner way to do this? 
b) If I do need to do it this way, can I avoid the "if" statement and utilize some functionality with Optional?

(Note: I cannot change the builder itself, and I cannot that the secondaryId is a String, but that what we retrieve from infoProvider is an optional)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A little bit cleaner would be to use `ifPresent`

```
secondaryId.ifPresent(input::setSecondaryId);
```

but that's pretty much the best you can get with these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I was just facing the same problem as the OP and came up with this abstraction, which integrates directly with the builder instead of later modifying the object via setters. It would work the same with a model that instead of builders just offers "wither" methods.

(using lombok)

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
class Modifier<T> {
    private final T value;

    public static <T> Modifier<T> modify(T initialValue) {
        return new Modifier<>(initialValue);
    }

    public <U> Modifier<T> ifPresent(Optional<U> optional, BiFunction<T, U, T> modifier) {
        return modify(optional.map(input -> modifier.apply(value, input)).orElse(value));
    }

    public T get() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Applied to the OP's example this would be used like this (again using lombok for generating the builder):

```
import static Modifier.modify;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

class ModifierTest {

    @Value
    @Builder
    static class SomeInput {
        String id;
        String secondaryId;
        String state;
    }

    SomeInput constructSomeInput(Optional<String> maybeSecondaryId, Optional<String> maybeState) {
        final SomeInput result = modify(SomeInput.builder().id("myId"))
            .ifPresent(maybeSecondaryId, (builder, secondaryId) -> builder.secondaryId(secondaryId))
            .ifPresent(maybeState, (builder, state) -> builder.state(state))
            .get()
            .build();
        return result;
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldBuildSomeInputWithSecondaryId() {
        final Optional<String> maybeSecondaryId = Optional.of("mySecondaryId");
        final Optional<String> maybeState = Optional.of("myState");
        final SomeInput result = constructSomeInput(maybeSecondaryId, maybeState);
        assertEquals("mySecondaryId", result.getSecondaryId());
        assertEquals("myState", result.getState());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldBuildSomeInputWithoutSecondaryId() {
        final Optional<String> maybeSecondaryId = Optional.empty();
        final Optional<String> maybeState = Optional.of("myState");
        final SomeInput result = constructSomeInput(maybeSecondaryId, maybeState);
        assertEquals(null, result.getSecondaryId());
        assertEquals("myState", result.getState());
    }
}
```